# Fail to serve an Angular 5.2 version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I currently have an Angular project in version 5.2 regarding the package.json file ( "@angular/core": "^5.2.0").

I am not able to run ng serve as I get this error message : The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

My question is : Do I HAVE to update the current Angular version and packages to serve this app ? And if yes, why am I not able to serve it in this configuration ?

Any help will be much appreciated.

[screenshot of the default project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdz8E.png)

--> PACKAGE.JSON <--

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng app",
    "build": "ng build && node server.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.1.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "npm": "^5.7.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
```

Comment: Which version of `ng` do you use?

Comment: @Henry, after running 'ng --version', I get this error message : ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/home/...'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/home/....'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:759:3)
    at VersionCommand.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/version-impl.js:48:41)
    at VersionCommand.validateAndRun (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:124:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: The error is clear, some answers already pointed out the solution.It thats not the case, then you need to add more information. Eg. package.json, ss of your folder structure and the path in which you execute ng serve

Comment: what version of the cli was used to generate that project?

Comment: I updated the original post with the package.json file guys, thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not running your project from the root location i.e. where package.json reside.

Try to move to that position and run ng build/serve.

Comment: I am running the command where the package.json is located. The error message is clear and says that the command is not run in the root location, but it actually is.

Comment: can you check your package.json file. i think it is not properly build.

Comment: Yes for sure, here are some informations :     "@angular/cli": "1.6.8", "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",  "typescript": "~2.5.3",  "@angular/material": "^5.2.1",

Comment: this all are dependency, did you have name, scripts, version in your file

Comment: Please check the original post as the package.json file is visible now.

Comment: instead of "ng serve" in start scripts you have "ng app". Do you able to build your project by ng build?

Comment: I have seen that yes. When i run 'ng build', the same error is coming : The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
The command is well executed in the project root folder.

Comment: "@angular/cli": "1.6.8" - why the cli is 1.6 if you are using angular v 5. try to update the angular cli version

Comment: I started by running 'npm uninstall -g angular-cli', which gave the response 'up to date.' I am guessing that angluar-cli is not installed.

Comment: that's strange, why uninstall command gave you 'up to date' response. Anyways just try to install 'npm install -g @angular/cli@latest'

Comment: Here the response I had from the command 'sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest' : /usr/bin/ng -> /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@7.3.0
updated 1 package in 8.937s

Comment: @angular/cli@7.3.0 updated 1 package in 8.937s - Angular cli updated. Now either you can update the local cli version or use global cli and try to run

Comment: Ohh.. first try to install all the dependency by using 'npm install'. then ng serve will differently run

Comment: Has been done, apparently some dependencies are missing : npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@~5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/common@~5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Okay so it is working, still not sure what happened, but I started with a fresh copy of the project, and simply ran 'npm install', and everything came together. Wow aha. Well, maybe I haven't started from the beginning. Thank you so much for your time @Ankur !

Answer (score 0):

Move to your angular project loaction and then give **ng serve**, It will work.

The error is because of you are trying to run the angular project in diffrent location.

> cd move_to_your_angular_application_folder

Comment: Thank you for your response @saravana. When Igive ng serve, I am already located in the application folder, where the project is located.

Comment: Can you able to find the package.json in your location where you are running the ng serve?

Comment: Yes, I run the command 'ng serve' where the folders e2e, server, src, app and the files package.json, tsconfig.json, angular-cli.json, ... are located.

Comment: ok cool!!, what are all the error you are getting? so that I can able to debug it.

Comment: When I run 'ng serve', I get : The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.